# Adaptar sub de VB a VBA

Tags: c#, vb.net, vba, ms-access

Estoy tratando de comunicar mediante *VBA* con un controlador de puertas marca *zkteco c100* usando el *SDK* de *zkteco*.

Hay una función `GetDeviceParam`  que me permite consultar los parámetros del dispositivo, pero no logro que me conteste, pienso que es en la implementación del *buffer*.

Este es mi código dentro de un módulo de *Access 2016*:

```vb
Public Declare Function Connect _
    Lib "c:\windows\system32\plcommpro.dll" _
    (ByVal Parameters As String) As Long
Public Declare Function PullLastError _
    Lib "c:\windows\system32\plcommpro.dll" _
    () As Integer
Public Declare Function SearchDevice _
    Lib "c:\windows\system32\plcommpro.dll" _
    (CommType As String, Address As String, buffer As Byte) As Long
Public Declare Function GetDeviceParam _
    Lib "c:\windows\system32\plcommpro.dll" _
    (h As Long, ByRef buffer As Byte, buffersize As Long, itemvalues As String) As Long
Public Declare Function Disconnect _
    Lib "c:\windows\system32\plcommpro.dll" _
    (ByVal h As Long)

Sub zkteco_test1()
Dim conerr As String

Dim valuesToRead As String
Dim ret As Long
Const buffersize As Double = (5 * 64 * 64)
Dim buffer(buffersize - 1) As Byte
Dim tmp As String
Dim param As String
Dim h As Long

param = "protocol=TCP,ipaddress=192.168.0.251,port=4370,timeout=2000,passwd="
'Connect es una funcion que inicia la comunicacion con el controlador y devuelve un numero positivo 
'para indicar que se realizo con exito la conexion
h = Connect(param)

valuesToRead = "GATEIPAddress,NetMask"
tmp = ""

'GetDeviceParam es la funcion que debe regresar los valores pedidos en valuesToRead dentro del buffer 
ret = GetDeviceParam(h, buffer(0), buffersize, valuesToRead)
tmp = BinaryToString(buffer(0))
MsgBox tmp
Rem tmp = Encoding.[Default].GetString(buffer)
Rem MsgBox ((convert.tostring("GetDeviceParam: ") & tmp) + ".")

Disconnect (h)
End Sub
```

Estoy atorado, pongo el código original en *C* y *VB* para referencia así como la información de la función.

```
4.11 SearchDevice
[Function]
int SearchDevice(char *CommType,char *Address, char *Buffer)
[Objective]
The function is used to search for the access control panel in the LAN.
[Parameter description]
CommType
[in]: If the communication type is set to UDP (or Ethernet), all devices of the specified communication type
will be searched.
Address
[in]: Broadcast address; the system searches for the devices in the LAN within the specified IP address
range; the default value is 255.255.255.255, known as network broadcasting.
Buffer
[in]: The buffer is used to save the detected devices. Users should determine the requested memory
according to the number of devices in the corresponding network. For example, if the network has not more
than 50 devices, it is recommended that users should request the memory of 32K; if the network has not
more than 100 devices, it is recommended that users should request the memory of 64K.
[Returned value]
When the returned value is 0 or a positive value, it indicates the number of found access control panels.
When the returned value is a negative value, it indicates that the operation fails. Attached table 5 lists the
information about the error codes.
[Note]
This approach is intended to search for access controllers on a LAN in UDP broadcast mode. UDP packets
cannot traverse routers, so an access controller must not be separated from a server by routers. If by this
means you find a device that resides on a different network segment as a server but fail to ping the IP
address of an access controller, you may set the controller and server addresses to be on the same subnet
(not necessarily on the same network segment). For details on network setting, consult related administrator
to obtain correct IP addresses, subnet masks and gateways.
[Example]
```

Python:

```py
dev_buf = create_string_buffer("", 64*1024)
ret=self.commpro.SearchDevice("UDP", "255.255.255.255", dev_buf)
```

C#

```cs
int ret = 0;
string udp = "UDP";
string adr = "255.255.255.255";
byte[] buffer = new byte[64 * 1024];
ret = SearchDevice(udp,adr, ref buffer[0]);
```

VB

```vb
[DllImport("plcommpro.dll", EntryPoint = "SearchDevice")]
//public static extern int SearchDevice( ref byte commtype, ref byte address, ref byte buffer);
public static extern int SearchDevice(string commtype, string address, ref byte buffer);
private void SearchDevice_Pull()
{
    Connect_Pull();
        int ret = 0, j = 0;
        byte[] buffer = new byte[64 * 1024];
        string str = "";
        string[] tmp = null;
        string udp = "UDP";
        string adr = "10.0.0.44";
    MessageBox.Show("Start to SearchDevice!");
    ret = SearchDevice(udp, adr, ref buffer[0]);
    MessageBox.Show("ret searchdevice=" + ret);
        if (ret >= 0)
    {
        str = Encoding.Default.GetString(buffer);
        str = str.Replace("\r\n", "\t");
        tmp = str.Split('\t');
        while (j < tmp.Length - 1)
        {
        string[] sub_str = tmp[j].Split(',');
            MessageBox.Show(tmp[0]);
        }
    }
         else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("SearchDevice operation is failed!");
        return;
    }
    Disconnect_pull();
}
```

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Estas atorado con que error?

Comment: Por que usa 10.0.0.44 para la dirección en VB cuando los otros usan 255.255.255.255?

Comment: duston, gracias por interesarte en la pregunta, esa es la direccion ip de la controladora que abre las puertas.

Comment: gbianchi, estoy atorado en como crear un array o buffer para recibir la informacion que me manda la controladora de puertas

Comment: En teoría se supone que declaro las funciones de la dll al inicio del modulo                                                 
     Public Declare Function SearchDevice _
         Lib "c:\windows\system32\plcommpro.dll" _
         (CommType As String, Address As String, buffer As Byte) As Long
     Public Declare Function GetDeviceParam _
         Lib "c:\windows\system32\plcommpro.dll" _
         (h As Long, ByRef buffer As Byte, buffersize As Long, itemvalues As String)  
         As Long

Comment: sin embargo al querer declarar el buffer o array según yo tengo errores de desbordamiento de memoria que solo logro quitar si reduzco el tamaño del buffer de esta manera                                                                                                   
     Const buffersize As Double = (5 * 64 * 64)
     Dim buffer(buffersize - 1) As Byte

Comment: yo se que ya tengo comunicación por que la función connect me devuelve el valor asignado al controlador de puertas y mientras no tenga que recibir datos me función sin errores

Answer (score 0):

Comprueba qué versión tienes instalada de Office. Si es por defecto tendrás la de 32 Bits. Y dependiendo de como estén programadas las dll te pueden dar problemas

[Aquí](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/office/vba/language/concepts/getting-started/64-bit-visual-basic-for-applications-overview) puedes ver una página de Microsoft que lo explica.

Básicamente, compruébalo tú mismo en la página de microsoft, yo entiendo que si tu aplicación de las puertas está programada en 64 Bits la declaración de las funciones serían del tipo:

```
Declare PtrSafe Function GetActiveWindow Lib "user32" () As LongPtr
```

Ya nos dirás. Un Saludo